# Facebook Post Id is null in OnActivityResult method of fragment in Android Application

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, android-fragments

I am trying to show the Facebook Post Id in a toast after i have successfully shared a post using sharedialog in my fragment,the control return to onActivityResult of the Activity and i am calling the fragment's onActivityResult from Activity's onActivityResult. In doing so i am getting post id as null.Is there a better way to retrieve the post id?